# ArrayList remove does not work

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove all the objects inside `walls` `ArrayList` with a for loop but I cant get it working

```
public void initializeButtons(){
    JButton save_button = new JButton("Save");
    save_button.addMouseListener(new Button_MouseListener(save_button));
    save_button.setBounds(1300, 50, 75, 50);
    add(save_button);

    JButton load_button = new JButton("Load");
    save_button.addMouseListener(new Button_MouseListener(load_button));
    load_button.setBounds(1300, 125, 75, 50);
    add(load_button);

    JButton reset_button = new JButton("Reset");
    save_button.addMouseListener(new Button_MouseListener(reset_button));
    reset_button.setBounds(1300, 200, 75, 50);
    add(reset_button);
}
```

This is part in `Button_MouseListener` responsible for handling `"Reset"` button

```
if (button.getText().equals("Reset")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
        walls.remove(((int)i));
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Note :
`walls.clear();` also does not work, and I'm not getting any error. It just does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like copy-paste mistake. When you copied

```
JButton save_button = new JButton("Save");
save_button.addMouseListener(new Button_MouseListener(save_button));
save_button.setBounds(1300, 50, 75, 50);
add(save_button);
```

you changed the name of the reference only in its declaration

```
JButton load_button = new JButton("Load");
```

but forgot to change it in the line below

```
save_button.addMouseListener(new Button_MouseListener(load_button));
```

which means that you are still adding a listener only to `save_button`, not to `load_button`.

Same thing happens for `reset_button` which means that code

```
if (button.getText().equals("Reset")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < walls.size(); i++) {
        walls.remove(((int)i));
    }
    repaint();
}
```

will never be executed by this button.

By the way, this loop makes no sense. If you wish to clear the `List`, call `clear()` method.

```
walls.clear();
```

The reason your loop will not work properly (even after you fix the listeners issue) is that `walls.remove(i)` removes the `i`'th element and makes the former `i+1`'s element the new `i`'th element (it shifts all elements after the `i`th left), which means you'll never remove that new element at position `i` because in the next iteration `i` will be incremented.